# Convert YouTube Playlist into Folders & Bookmarks

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, file-conversion

How can I convert YouTube playlist into organized browser (preferably Chrome) folders and bookmarks? I've got CSV files downloaded from Google Takeout for each playlist that contains playlist ID, playlist title & video ID, and want to convert them into organized browser folders and bookmarks.

Is there a tool or method that I can use to achieve that purpose, also fetching video titles and put into bookmark title, since the CSV doesn't contain the video title?

I found an [web tool by Jefferson Scher](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/res/youtube-playlist-to-bookmarks.html) but it requires a JSON file as input. It seems Google Takeout no longer output YouTube playlist in JSON anymore.

Comment: You can try converting CSV to JSON with [this tool](https://csvjson.com/csv2json).

Comment: @tomasantunes Thanks but I tried the tool and the format is not accepted by the JSON to bookmark tool. Got "unidentified properties" error.